# How to compare two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, database

I have two dataframes:

- The first one has n row of names.
- The second one has n row of names.

for each name in the first dataframe:

- see how many times it appears in the second dataframe.

The code looks something like this:

```
df5 = pd.read_excel(item1, usecols="B",skiprows=6)
df10 = pd.read_excel('SMR4xx_Change_situation.xlsm', sheet_name='LoPN',usecols='D', skiprows=4)
```

how do i count the number of times a name appears in the second database and output it besides the name in the first database?

Ex: The first name in the database is John. John appears in the second dataframe 4 times => output John 4

either print it in the console or write in a separate excel file the first database and on the second column the number of appearances.

Anything could help.

Comment: Something like ```df1.merge(df2["Name"].value_counts().rename("Number of Occurences"), on="Name")```. For a more detailed answer, pls provide an example of what dataframes look like.

Comment: The first dataframe looks something like this: A2AA,A2AB,A2AC,A2AD.... The second looks something  like this : A2AB, A2AD, A2AD, A2AC, A2AA, A2AC... I need to take the first dataframe and write the number of appearances in the second dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can create a datarame for the records you are seeking.
You can first get list of unique names in the first dataframe like

```
uniqueNames = df5['B'].unique()  # Assuming column B contains the names

dfCount = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'count'])
```

Now you can iterate through each of the unique names in the first dataframe and compare against the second dataframe like this:

```
for eachName in uniqueNames:
    dfCount = dfCount.append({'name':eachName, 
                              'count':(df10['D'] == eachName).sum()}, 
                              ignore_index=True)  # Assuming you need to compare with column D
```

Or
If you want the counts to be present in the first database, something like this should work

```
import numpy as np
df10['counts'] = np.nan
df10['counts'] = np.select([dfCount['name']==df5['B']], [dfCount['count']], np.nan)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. How do I write the number of appearances besides each name in the first database?

Comment: I have updated the answer for that as well, it will add another column to the first dataframe and assign the counts.

Comment: Im sorry for asking but can you give me a way to contact you so you can explain it to me better? I am a beginner and i am really struggling. thank you so much

Comment: You can mark answer as accepted if it worked for you. If you want to reach out to me, you can text me in stackoverflow.